# How can I do comparison in Date()

Tags: swift

I want to perform a Date() comparison calculation

I have a String return date of the form:

```
let expirationDate "2023-11-16T10:44:00+0000
```

I want to do the following comparison:

```
If expirationDate - currentDate < 70h (~259200s) {
    --- implement A
} else {
   --- implement B
}
```

My idea is to convert it all to seconds, then the comparison will be done

But I am getting an error as follows:

> Referencing operator function '<' on 'BinaryInteger' requires that 'CGFloat' conform to 'BinaryInteger'

Below is my code

```
func updateComponents() {
    let expirationString = "2023-11-16T10:44:00+0000"
    let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: expirationString)

    guard let date = date else { return }
    let expirationCount = date.timeIntervalSince1970
    let currentDateCount = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

    let seconds = 259200
    if expirationCount - currentDateCount < seconds {
        // implement A
    } else {
        // implement B

    }
}
```

Comment: You should use the `Calendar` class to add 70 hours to the current date and then do a direct comparison between the two dates. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293453-date

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Comparison operators need both sides to be the same type.
- Swift infers `seconds` as `Int`.
- The left-side type is `TimeInterval`.
- One of them has to be converted.

You can implicitly make the `seconds` be a `TimeInterval`:

```
let seconds: TimeInterval = 259200
```

Also, you can use the `timeIntervalSince` instead of a subtraction like:

```
try! Date("2053-11-16T10:44:00+0000", strategy: .iso8601).timeIntervalSince(.now) < seconds
```

<sub>⚠️ Note that you may consider using the `calendar` to get the difference between dates. [Here is an example why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77465185/5623035)</sub>

Comment: but I don't want the "!", Do you have any other way to write it?

Comment: :) That's just an example my friend. You can use your own method for generating dates from a text. Also,e there is nothing wrong with force try when you hardcoded the value and sure about the result.